# How to combine values of Variables into a string in C

Tags: c, string, variables

Is there a way to combine three or more variables with values in "int" into a string. Say i want to combine the values of a,b,c in a single string, and then further prints those values using their variables from the string.

Comment: It is not very clear what you want in the second part of the question. Please give some simple example.

Comment: Do you just mean `printf("%d,%d,%d\n", a, b, c)`?

Answer (score 8):

To put three ints into a string:

```
   int numbers[3] = { 1, 2, 3 };
   char string[1024];
   sprintf(string, "%d %d %d", numbers[0], numbers[1], numbers[2]);
```

The string can then be printed using normal means. `sprintf()` is a version of `printf()` that prints into a `char*` just as `fprintf()` prints to a `FILE*`.

As Jonathan Leffler observes, a pitfall of `sprintf()` is that you can overflow your char buffer.  For this reason there is an `snprintf()` which allows you to specify a maximum length for the input:

```
    snprintf(string, 1024, "%d %d %d", numbers[0], numbers[1], numbers[2]);
```

Comment: For further information consult the [sprintf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sprintf/) page at cplusplus.com.

Comment: Given the size of `string`, you have more than enough space to spare, but in general, using `snprintf()` rather than `sprintf()` is a good idea.

Comment: I was going to say, you'd have to have quite a lot of `ULLONG_MAX`es, but best use `snprintf` as examples to people who are new to C.

Comment: 50 values of 18446744073709551615 would cause problems